# Celery - Iterating over tasks as they complete

Tags: python, celery

Maybe I am misunderstanding something about celery but I have been stuck on this for quite a while.

I have a bunch of simple subtasks that I want to run in parallel, and I want to iterate over them as they complete rather than waiting for all of them to complete. I tried this:

```
def task_generator():
   for row in db:
      yield mytask.s(row)

from celery.result import ResultSet
r = ResultSet(t.delay() for t in task_generator())
for result in r.iterate():
    print result
```

However celery runs all of the tasks first and the iteration begins only after all of the tasks are completed, despite the docs for `ResultSet.iterate` reading `"Iterate over the return values of the tasks as they finish one by one."`

So how do I iterate over the task results as they are completed?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this, and have used it in the past. I think `.iterate()` is deprecated though, so I am working on a new solution myself.

```py
@task
def task_one(foo, bar):
    return foo + bar

subtasks = []
for x in range(10):
    subtasks.append(task_one.s(x, x+1))

results = celery.Group(subtasks)()  # call this
for result in results.iterate(propagate=False):
    answer = result.iteritems().next()
```